# How to remove command duplicates?

Tags: windows-10, powershell

The new PowerShell has a default irritating feature of keeping duplicate commands in the keyboard buffer.  For example, if I had executed the command `DIR` ten times, pushing the `Up Arrow` will show ten `DIR` entries.

I tried to check the `Discard Old Duplicates` box in Properties/Options, but this did not work.

How do I turn off duplicate commands?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PowerShell in Windows 10 use `PSReadline` for better command line editing experience. `PSReadline` does not use normal console input buffer and so not affected by `Discard Old Duplicates` option. You should disable duplicates in `PSReadline` options:

```
Set-PSReadlineOption -HistoryNoDuplicates
```

You have to put that in your PowerShell profile, if you want this as default behavior.

Comment: Thanks.  This has been annoying me for some time -- but just got around to looking up how to take care of it.